# Passing a 2D array to a function taking a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int **);
int main(void)
{
    int ptr[2][3] = { {8, 7, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
    printf("ptr point is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("*ptr point is %p\n", *ptr);
    func(ptr);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void func(int *ptr[8])
{
    printf("ptr point is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("*ptr point is %p\n", *ptr);
    printf("*(ptr + 1) point is %p\n", *(ptr + 1));
}
```

Output:

```
ptr point is 004FFC24
*ptr point is 004FFC24
ptr point is 004FFC24
*ptr point is 00000008
*(ptr + 1) point is 00000007
Press any key to continue
```

Why `ptr` now becomes a 1D pointer?

As you can see
`*(ptr)` in `func()` output a 8; 
`*(ptr + 1)` in `func()` output a 7;they are all digits in the array,
However, `ptr` should be 2D pointer, (because [] match with *, consequently `*ptr[8]` should match with `**ptr`).
so `*(ptr + 1)` and `*(ptr)` should be 1D pointers, instead of digits?

Comment: your code is surprising. You declared `func(char**)` but later defined it as `func(int**)`

Comment: This code is wrong,  if you do not see error messages then change your compiler settings. You are just confusing yourself by trying to make sense of the output of an invalid program

Comment: I am so sorry for my wrong typying that waste your precious time..........

Comment: @Newhawkins: It’s no big deal.  Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks  for your advice.and It's so nice of you to help me again.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues.

First, you declare `func` to take a `char **`, but later define it to take `int *[8]`, which doesn’t match.  Even worse, both are wrong - or rather, they don’t match the type of the argument you’re passing.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type “N-element of `T`” will be converted (“decay”) to an expression of type “pointer to `T`”, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

When you pass `ptr` to `func`, it is converted from type “2-element array of 3-element array of `int`” to “pointer to 3-element array of `int`”, or `int (*)[3]`.  So the function prototype needs to be

```
void func( int (*ptr)[3] )
```

or

```
void func( int ptr[][3] )
```

Because your function definition and declarations don’t match, and because neither matches the actual type of the argument, you get the unexpected output.  You *should* have gotten a warning on the mismatched function argument types; if not, you may need to raise the warning level.

Comment: I am really sorry for my type wrong, it should be int **;

Comment: And i seems to realize that the argument passed  should be matched , but i think that it just pass its value into the **func**, or  it should pass both the value and its type. Thank you again for helping me out!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!